# Technical issue with kendo combobox server filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I have implemented kendo combo box with cascading feature in my MVC 5 application. I am trying to implement server filtering and have hit a road block.

The combo box shows customer number and name concatenated as display text. I am trying to implement filtering as the user types a few characters. I have technically two problems here. The first one is how do I pass the filter text to the controller. I have written a javascript function to return the filtered text but already have the data attribute set to another function called GetSalesOfficeFilter.

The second problem that I am having is that the filter is on concatenated field Name1 and Customer Number of my view model whereas the linq query that I have written has access only to the model which does not contain the concatenated field. How do I get this working ?

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })

                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.CustomerMasterDataId)

                     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                    .DataTextField("CustomerNumberName")
                    .Placeholder("Select...")
                    .DataValueField("CustomerMasterDataId")
                    .Filter("contains")
                    .MinLength(3)
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                          .Read(read =>
                          {
                              read.Action("RequestHeader_CustomerData", "Request")
                                  .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
                                  .Data("GetSalesOfficeFilter");
                          }).ServerFiltering(true)
                                    ).CascadeFrom("CountryCode").Filter("contains")

                       .Events(e =>
                       {
                           e.Change("onCustomerComboChange");
                       })
                            )
                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult RequestHeader_CustomerData(string id,string filter)
        {
            var response = requestRepository.GetCustomerData(id).AsQueryable().Where(i => i.Name1.Contains(filter)).ProjectTo<CustomerViewModel>();

            var jsonResult = Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return jsonResult;
        }
```

javascript

```
function GetSalesOfficeFilter() {

    return { id: $('#CountryCode').val() }
};


function onAdditionalData() {
        return {
            filter: $("#Name1").data("kendoComboBox").text()
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Kendo Dinamic Linq` library for server filtering.
But for correct work you cant use mappers or something which can materialize your query.

Here example of how you can do that kendo-way:

```
using Kendo.DynamicLinq;

public class EmployeesController : Controller {

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Get(int take, int skip, IEnumerable<Kendo.DynamicLinq.Sort> sort, Kendo.DynamicLinq.Filter filter) {
    var employees = _context.Employees.OrderBy(e => e.Employee_ID)
      .OrderBy(e => e.Employee_ID)
      .Select(e => new Models.Employee {
        EmployeeID = e.Employee_ID,
        FirstName = e.First_Name,
        LastName = e.Last_Name,
        Title = e.Title,
        BirthDate = e.Birth_Date
    });

    return Json(employees.ToDataSourceResult(take, skip, sort, filter));
  }
}
```

Check out [docs](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/kendo-ui-open-sources-dynamic-linq-helpers)

But if you can't or won't use new libraries, there is another way.
Before sending request to server, you can parse filters in [parametrMap function](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) on client and send only one parameter which you will handle on server.